# Access object attributes and display component in a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, fetch-api

I want to access information using the ID in Entry_test.js and display it through another component that is DisplayEntry.js. I have fetched the ID from Entry_test.js and linked DisplayEntry.js with it, but when I am trying to access the attribute of the object being displayed that is {crypto.name} in DisplayEntry.js, it is not displaying anything. And also I am not able to open new page when clicking on the link. Here is my code:

App.js-

```
import React  from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

//import Exchange from './components/Exchange';
//import Entry from './components/Entry';
import DisplayEntry from './components/DisplayEntry';
import Entry_test from './components/Entry_test';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){
  return(

    <div>
       <NavBar/>

       <Route path="/entry" excat component={Entry_test}/>
       {/* <Route excat path="/exchange" component={Exchange}/> */}
       <Route path="/entry/:id" component={DisplayEntry}/>

      </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Entry_test.js-

```
import React,  {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Table} from 'reactstrap'
import {Form,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
// import style from './style.css'
// import Loading from './loading.gif';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";


const CoinGecko = require('coingecko-api');
const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

function Display(){

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchItems();
    },[]);

    const[cryptos,setCryptos]=useState([]);

    const fetchItems=async()=>{
           const info = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.all();
            console.log(info.data);
            setCryptos(info.data)


    }

    const cryptoJsx=cryptos.map(crypto=>(
        <tr key={crypto.id}>
                <td className="point">
                <img src={crypto.image.thumb}  alt="symbol"/>
                <Link  to={`/entry/${crypto.id}`}>{crypto.id}</Link></td>
                <td className="point">{crypto.symbol}</td>
                <td className="point">{crypto.name}</td>
                <td className="point">{crypto.market_data.current_price.usd}</td>
                <td className="point">{crypto.market_data.total_volume.usd}</td>                   

        </tr>
    ));

    return(
        <div>                    
                <h2 className="text-capitalize text-center my=5">Cryptocurrencies </h2>
                <div className="float-right p-2">
                <Form inline>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" 
                onChange={(event)=>this.search(event.target.value)}/>
                <Button >Search</Button>
                </Form>
                </div>
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                            <tr className="text-center">
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Current Price</th>
                            <th>Total Volume</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {cryptoJsx} 
                        </tbody>
                </Table>

            </div>
    );

}
export default Display
```

DisplayEntry.js-

```
import React,  {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

// const CoinGecko = require('coingecko-api');
// const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

function Display_info({match}){

    useEffect(()=>{
      fetchItemDis();
      console.log(match); 

    },[]);

    const[crypto , setCrypto]=useState({});

    const fetchItemDis= async() =>{
      let fetchDatadis= await fetch
      (`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=${match.params.id}&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`);

      const data_dis=await fetchDatadis.json();
    //  const data_dis= await CoinGeckoClient.coins.fetchMarketChart(`${match.params.id}`);
      setCrypto(data_dis);
      console.log(data_dis)
    };       

    return(
      <div>
        {crypto.name}
      </div>

    );

}
export default Display_info
```

Comment: Please format your code. When your code uses inconsistent formatting it becomes hard to read. You don't have to do it by hand either, there are many tools that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make some minor changes here:

```
import DisplayInfo from "./components/DisplayEntry";
import Display from "./components/Entry_test";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default function App(props) {

  return (
    <Router>
        {/* <NavBar /> */}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Display} />
        {/* <Route excat path="/exchange" component={Exchange}/> */}
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/entry/:id" component={DisplayInfo} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

You can change the initial path back to "/enter".
You will need to import BrowserRouter as Router and set children components to Router.
Also import Switch for the different paths "/entry/:id" which will pass the id parameter to match property in DisplayInfo.

In your DisplayInfo to see the value you are receiving an Array of Objects and the first array is 0 so:

```
const [crypto, setCrypto] = useState(null);

return(
      <div>
        {crypto === null ? "loading..." : crypto[0].name}
      </div>

    );
```

This will show the name.

Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-wave-06f7b

Please accept as answer.

Comment: I just updated it forgot to save my work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitcoin-example-06f7b

Comment: After adding the <Switch>, still my component in not opening a new page, it is displaying information in the same page. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: You don't need the swtich I completely removed it and it still works.  The switch works if you are using multiple paths using same params.  You can checkout the update from the former link.

Comment: I tried that thing but the problem still persists. 
I have made a small test code for this. please check : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-engelbart-u98bu
In this, when I am clicking on the data on Entry.js , it is displaying the information on the same page rather than opening in the new page. 
What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: You're spelling exact wrong change:

<Route excat path="/entry"  component={Entry}/>

to:

<Route exact path="/entry"  component={Entry}/>